# SOAP response by given request and response structure in PHP

Tags: php, soap

As I am pretty new to SOAP I really need some help to get started. I have been given this structur:

**request:**

```
    POST /NumbriParing/NumbriParing.asmx HTTP/1.1
Host: nba.tja.ee
Content-Type: text/xml; charset=utf-8
Content-Length: length
SOAPAction: "http://nba.sa.ee/NumriomanikuParing"

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<soap:Envelope xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
  <soap:Body>
    <NumriomanikuParing xmlns="http://nba.sa.ee/">
      <number>long</number>
    </NumriomanikuParing>
  </soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>
```

**Response:**

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Content-Type: text/xml; charset=utf-8
Content-Length: length

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<soap:Envelope xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
  <soap:Body>
    <NumriomanikuParingResponse xmlns="http://nba.sa.ee/">
      <NumriomanikuParingResult>
        <Number>long</Number>
        <OmanikuRegNumber>string</OmanikuRegNumber>
        <Omanik>string</Omanik>
        <VastusKood>NumberLeitud or NumbritEiLeitud</VastusKood>
      </NumriomanikuParingResult>
    </NumriomanikuParingResponse>
  </soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>
```

I need to replace the "long" placeholder in the request with a numeric variable to get the request for that number. 
The asmx is located in https://nba.tja.ee/NumbriParing/NumbriParing.asmx
How Can it be done using php?

Best regards,
Martti

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [SoapClient](http://www.php.net/manual/en/soapclient.soapclient.php) and WSDL of the service you need.
Something like:

```
try {
    $client = new SoapClient('https://nba.tja.ee/NumbriParing/NumbriParing.asmx?WSDL');
    $param = new stdClass();
    $param->number = 123;
    $result = $client->NumriomanikuParing($param);

    var_dump($result);
} catch (Exception $e) {
    echo "Error: " . $e->getMessage();
}
```

Comment: Thank you. It works. I couldn't imagine that SoapClient is so easy to use.